# drupal User profile changes

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

is it possible to get the updated fields when a user updates his profile.ie If he updates first name and last name then i want that both fields only.
Is there any module to fetch the updated modules or any other methods to do this???
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the core profile module or content profile?

Comment: am using the core profile module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no. You might be able to implement such a thing yourself using [hook_user()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_user/6) and insert/update `$op`s. Doing a similar thing with nodes in `hook_nodeapi` you'd call `node_load` on the `nid` of the node being acted upon, and that would give you the old node, in it's unchanged state (because Drupal does not reset the cache from `node_load` until later on. This is apparently by design.

Similarly in `hook_user()` you might be able to call `user_load()` to get the old user details, run through each of the object's values and compare them against the new user object, telling you exactly what had changed. This totally depends on at what Drupal clears the static cache for the user following an insert/update though. The only way you'll know is by reading the code in the user module or just trying it out.